# How to make a number spirale front cover to a book?

Tags: pgfmath, covers, bookcover

**UPDATE:** I'm currently rewriting a new edition with my math teacher's self-published maths textbook. I have looked online for similar problems with number spirals cover but couldn't find anything satisfying. I've been taken inspiration from [this graphic](https://www.shutterstock.com/sv/image-vector/modern-vector-abstract-brochure-book-flyer-250370206) from Shutterstock. I want it to look kind of like this:

[image]

and as you can see, I want the number spiral in this particular way. But I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Georgia}
\setsansfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Arial}

\usepackage{pgfmath}

\newcommand\randmin{0}
\newcommand\randmax{9}

\newcommand\setValues[1]{
    \pgfmathparse{%
        #1 / 3 + 36
    }%
   \xdef\curFontSize{\pgfmathresult}%

    \pgfmathparse{%
        int( rnd * ( \randmax - \randmin + 1 ) + \randmin )
    }%
   \xdef\curRand{\pgfmathresult}%

    \pgfmathparse{%
        #1 * 2 + 360 / (#1 + 0.1)
    }%
   \xdef\curAngle{\pgfmathresult}%

    \pgfmathparse{%
        rnd * 180 + \curAngle + 90
    }%
   \xdef\curJitter{\pgfmathresult}%

    \pgfmathparse{%
        rnd * 10 + #1 - 5
    }%
   \xdef\curRadius{\pgfmathresult}%
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        overlay, 
        remember picture, 
        shift={(current page.center)},
        number spiral/.style={
            text=blue,
            opacity=0.5,
        }
    ]
        \foreach \a [count=\r] in {0, 5, ..., 180} {
            \setValues{\a}
            \node[
                number spiral,
                rotate=\curJitter,
                font=\fontsize{\curFontSize pt}{\curFontSize pt}\selectfont\bfseries
            ] at (\curAngle:\curRadius mm) {\curRand{}};
        }
        \foreach \a [count=\r] in {0, 13, ..., 180} {
            \setValues{\a}
            \node[
                number spiral,
                text=orange,
                opacity=0.7,
                rotate=\curJitter,
                font=\fontsize{\curFontSize pt}{\curFontSize pt}\selectfont\bfseries
            ] at (\curAngle:\curRadius mm) {\curRand{}};
        }
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which produces this:

[image]

Notice the use of the `fontspec` package; requires LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have. See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: Sry for the late reply. I have my code now :)